# Undefined Variable PHP Error

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$backlinks=array($_POST['backlinks']);
$data=0; //If removed results in error
$data=implode($data,$backlinks[0]);
echo $data;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have got this undefined variable php error on $data.I have fixed it by initializing $data=0 but that's not my problem.I read in php variable initialization is not required.Then why it happens so?I have read most of the entries here regarding this but nothing explains the reason behind this.I need only expert advice.Please don't post some links just for votes.Thank You.

Comment: Have you read the documentation on `implode()`? - http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Well you use a variable that is undefined, what do you expect?

Comment: If you demand expert advise, you should present a question that requires expert advise, not trivia tips. Also, it's customary to use some spacing after periods.

Comment: @mario and anas:Nobody asked you or expect you to answer my question.If you think my question is below your standards then why the **** you comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not required for assignment but you're calling implode and passing it as an argument. Since it's undefined, PHP will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

When you reference it without declaring it, definitely will it throw an warning.

Answer (score 0):

You could write the line $ data = implode($data="",$backlinks[0]); and have the $data instantiate when it is passed to implode.