# Undefined variable in PHP in this math code

Tags: php, variables, undefined

please help me this code, when i click button, it shows

```
Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\tinhtong_luatoantu.php on line 47
```

```php
<?php 
    $nhapso1 = isset($_GET['so1']) ? $_GET['so1'] : '-1';
    $nhapso2 = isset($_GET['so2']) ? $_GET['so2'] : '-1';
    $pheptinh = $_GET['toantu'];
    if ($nhapso1 < 0 || $nhapso2 < 0) {
        echo 'Vui lòng nhập vào toán hạng & chọn toán tử';
    }
    else {
        switch($pheptinh) {
            case '------':
                echo 'Vui lòng nhập vào toán hạng & chọn toán tử';
                break;
            case '+':
                $result = $nhapso1 + $nhapso2;
                break;
            case '-':
                $result = $nhapso1 - $nhapso2;
                break;
            case '*':
                $result = $nhapso1 * $nhapso2;
                break;
            case '/':
                $result = $nhapso1 / $nhapso2;
                break;
            default:
                echo '';
                break;
        }
        echo round($result, 2);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined Variable PHP Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219977/undefined-variable-php-error)

Comment: Not seeing/counting a Line 47.

Comment: You are defining $result only in some cases. You can initialize it before switch begin: $result = 0; or assign some value to it in each case.

Answer (score 0):

In switch cases when your argument doesn't match with the given value it runs default case. In your code, when running the default case there is no declared $result variable which you echo at the end of the code. You should set the default value for $result either beginning of the code or default case. Simply say PHP compiler doesn't run codes that have in fail cases. So there is no $result when running default statement in switch case.

Comment: Thanks so much, but can you help me edit this code? I am a beginner

Comment: I can give some help to you if you can explain what is the business logic you going to achieve with this piece of code.

Answer (score -1):

That's because if the first case of the switch statement gets executed you are not defining **$result** variable and the same is with the **default case**. To avoid this, you can **initialise the result variable with a default value (let's say 0) before your switch statement starts**